# Does convergence in $L^2$ imply smallness of $||f_n-f||_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus B_R(0)}$ for large $R>0$ independent of $n$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Let $f_n,f: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ be real functions in $L^2$ so that $f_n\to f$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$. Does this already imply
\begin{align}
||f_n-f||_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus B_R(0))}\to 0
\end{align}
for all $n$ as $R\to \infty$?

Comment: What do you think ?

Comment: @Surb I think its wrong but I can't find a counterexample...

Comment: Of course it's true using Dominated convergence theorem. Notice that $$|f_n-f|^2\boldsymbol 1_{\mathbb R^2\setminus B_R(0)}\leq |f_n-f|^2\in L^1.$$